# pv_ops Kernel ignoring cpu hotplug under Xen 4 DomU

Tags: xen, central-processing-unit, debian-squeeze

I have a Xen 4.0.1 DomU running Debian Squeeze with the stock 2.6.32-5 Kernel. When I add CPUs via `xm-vcpu-set` they correctly show up in

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu
```

but are not set online and therefore are not available to the system until I manually set them online via

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/online
```

Removing vcpus works as advertised. Any I idea? Am I missing something or is this a bug / outstanding feature?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like pv_ops kernel do not take the CPUs added by the hypervisor 
online by default, one has to create an udev-rule for it like:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="cpu[0-9]*", RUN+="/bin/bash -c '/bin/sleep 10; echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/%k/online'"
```

( I put it in /etc/udev/rules.d/40-xen.rules )

To be honest I have no idea if this is already installed in a apckage 
I'm missing in my installation, but this works for me.